# Log periodic power Law data-fiting

Tags: periodic-functions, data-analysis

Good day,

I have to start working on data fitting problem, but I do not know how to start.

I have found this equation can work as the curve around which data will fit.

$y_t = A + B(t_c - t)^\beta[1+C \cos(\omega \log (t_c -t) + \phi)] $

where
$\beta = \frac{\log \mu}{\log \lambda}   $,

$\omega = \frac{2\pi}{\log \lambda} $

Now question is that from a given dataset say $x=[1..1200]$ and $y \text{ is fluctuating values from 200 to 800}$

how can we find $\mu$ and $\lambda$ ?

To give an idea when I plot the data I get

[image]

EDIT:
from the paper I read:(financial crash)

$y_t > 0 \ is \text{ price index or log of price at time t }$
$A>0 \text{ is the value y_t would have if bubble were to last until critical time}\ t_c$
$B< 0 \text{increase in }y_t \text{utill before crash} $

$C \text{ is the magnitude of the fluctuations around exponential growth }$

$t_c \text{ is critical time}$ , $t<t_c \text{ is time into the bubble}$,
$\phi \text{ is shift parameter}$ ,
$\beta = 0.33 +\pm 0.18 \text{ exponent of power law growth}$

$\omega =6.36 \pm 1.56 \text{ frequency of fluctuation during the buble}$

When I draw this function from the paper.. it looks like this.(not exact. But gives idea about the curve)

[image]

NOTE: original paper can be found here..
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45899349_Fitting_the_Log_Periodic_Power_Law_to_financial_crashes_a_critical_analysis

Comment: What about $A,B,C,t_c$ and $\phi$ ?

Comment: I edited original post. I hope I did not make it more confusing. If I failed then I will remove my post.. :) ..

Comment: The cited paper has under **4 - Fitting the LPPL parameters** how to find those parameters...